# JavaScript (Jquery) Decimal Point Removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

Currently I am working on JavaScript, jQuery, HTML5 to improve myself. I have a opensourcely coded clock, which I have converted it into a counter (reverse counter).

Problem I am having is, in my `setInterval(){...}` I have four variables -> second,min,hour, and day. The problem is, when I get the seconds, I get something like 1.155, 2.312, 3.412 (seconds).

My setInterval function is below

```
setInterval(function(){
//var duration = parseInt(Date.now() /1000 ) - 1365470000;


var futureTime = Date.parse('April 10, 2013 22:00:00');

var duration = (( parseInt(Date.now() - futureTime ) / 1000));


var seconds = duration % 60;
duration = parseInt(duration / 60);
var minutes = duration % 60;
duration = parseInt(duration / 60);
var hours = (duration)%24;
duration = parseInt(duration / 24);
var days = duration % 365;  


        animation(gVars.green, seconds, 60);
        animation(gVars.blue, minutes, 60);
        animation(gVars.orange, hours, 24);
        animation(gVars.red, days, 365);

    },1000);

}
```

And my output is below for some random time since i use `parseInt(Date.now())`.

> I have to give the link since I don't have enough rep.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zkbi.png

How can I get rid of the decimal point in `setInterval(){}` functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can see, set interval isn't running exactly every 1 second, instead it's running every 1.1 or so seconds. There's going to be a decimal, you just have to round it up or down.

Comment: `parseInt(seconds, 10) -> if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0'+seconds;`

Comment: Why aren't you using the Javascript Date functions like `getHours()`, `getSeconds()`, etc.?

Comment: If you mean you just want to round to an integer, check out the Math functions on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math). If you mean you want to invoke `setInterval` every second exactly, this isn't possible as browsers throttle this method in unpredictable ways.

Comment: @NathanBouscal , I also have tried that one. It doesn't work either.Using it right before the update. [at]adeneo , Checked it, doesn't work. [at]Barmar Its not a clock, It is a counter so I prefer using this one. [at]Graham as I told Nathan, floor doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Floor works, you're just using it wrong. Are you assigning the floored value back to the variable? It doesn't mutate the variable.

Comment: @NathanBouscal , Yes sir I just figured it out that I duplicated seconds while I am trying to fix it. After removing the duplicated one it just worked. It was simple. I feel ashamed, should have thought about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript offers more convinient API to work with date and time in order to fetch seconds, minutes, hours and days. Try this code:

```
var duration,
    seconds,
    minutes,
    hours;

duration = new Date((new Date('April 11, 2013 23:00:00')) - (new Date()));
seconds = duration.getSeconds();
minutes = duration.getMinutes();
hours = duration.getHours();
```

Now you will have integer values in all 4 variables above, without any decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

```
var seconds = 1234.13;
var seconds = seconds + '';

seconds = seconds.split('.')[0];

console.log(seconds);
```

Comment: I have also tried it before, but If I use that way, the degree of image is increasing more than 1 second's degree. So the second part of clock is increasing 1 second per sec but the graphic wise its 20~ secs.

Comment: And what if you only manipulate the output itself, so the actual second you are storing isn't getting rounded. You can only use `(seconds.split('.')+'')[0]` at the absolute point where you print the data. Then it shouldn't be affected by other data manipulation.

Comment: It works too, but I just figured out that Math.floor() function is enough to solve the problem. Thanks !